# Update if data is exist

Tags: uitableview, core-data

How to update the data if it is already exist in the database, when we click on the button save?
Thanks for your help.

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.recipe managedObjectContext];

if (!self.material) {
    self.material = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Material" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [self.recipe addMaterialsObject:self.material];
    self.material.displayOrder = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.recipe.materials.count]; 
    }    
[self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on you how you define instances of your `Material` entity to be equal. For example, is 100g flour and 200g flour the same (they should be, and you should find a way to separate quantity from ingredient...).

You can implement a method `isEqualToMaterial:(Material*)otherMaterial` and compare the essential attributes, like name and perhaps category. Before inserting a new entity object you could instead use the existing one.

However, from your code I see that you store a `displayOrder` in the material object, which depends on the number of materials in the recipe. That would presumably overwrite any existing `displayOrder` - so your current setup with multiple largely identical materials, while not ideal, might be what you want.

Maybe you should re-think your data model setup and devise a way where the user can *choose* from a list of ingredients before starting to type in his own.

Comment: what i want to make is that if the name of material is inserted the same as in the previous record, it must update the previous record with the newly inserted. inside the Material entity, there are two attribute: name and amount. so if the name is the same in the previous record. it update the previous record automatically. :D

Comment: Sorry, this does not make any sense. How can you insert a new name and overwrite an existing material with a different name, if you do not even know which other material to overwrite. - *I think you are way over your head in this project. Do something simpler first.*